# How we can justify UDP as connection-less and TCP as connection-oriented protocol?

Tags: networking

How we can justify UDP as connection-less and TCP as connection-oriented because in both the protocols we use concepts of ports and sockets for the process to process communication. In what way we can say that UDP is a connection-less protocol.

Comment: Not a question and on the wrong Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Let say, that communication is a talk. mean, two (or more) entities came to exchange information between their.

UDP doesn't verify that the messages reached their destination, and the order of the messages is not guaranteed. so you can say that is more like as the target bombing with the messages than like communication between entities.

Answer (score 0):

UDP is connectionless protocol
   --When a packet is sent over the network it doesn't care if the packet is received or not, invalid or valid. This is also called a stateless communication.
   --the client may also received a packet or data in sequence or out of sequence
   --UDP is common in audio/video streaming

TCP has a connection state
   --TCP has an overhead than UDP because it must verify if the packet sent over the network is valid and in proper sequnce (if invalid then it tries to resend the packet).

Answer (score 0):

There is no connect phase or disconnect phase in the UDP protocol. Ergo it is connectionless. I don't see what ports and sockets have to do with it. They are just local end points.

Contrary to several other answers, data ACKS and retries have nothing to do with it either. You can have a connection-oriented protocol without them.